# How to GET a file uploaded from a form to get displayed to another view using Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Newbie to Rails here. So I'm creating an online library for my project where I am able to upload e-books (in the forms of pdfs) of the user's choice. The form, Add Manga takes in two files: the thumbnail (in jpg, jpeg, png) and the actual pdf of the ebook.

I would like to know how to get both the thumbnail and the pdf files from the forms, and display it in my show view.

Thank you!

1) I've tried bringing in the img tag inside the label tag, however with the current script, returning nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="information">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p><%= @book.title%></p>
    <h1>Author</h1>
    <p><%= @book.author%></p>
    <h1>Description</h1>
    <p><%= @book.description%></p>
  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_book_path(@book), :class => "btn btn-default" %>
<!--after you make this make edit method in books controller-->
<%= button_to "Delete", book_path(@book),
    method: :delete,
    data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'},
    :class => "btn btn-danger" %>

</body>
</html>

This is my books controller. 
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index  #step 4
    @books = Book.all
  end

  def show #step 3
    @book = Book.find(params[:id]) #get individual post page
  end

  def newBook 
    @book = Book.new
    #creates a new post of registered books 
  end

  def create #Step 2
    #render plain: params[:books].inspect #see what data is sent
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    if(@book.save)
      redirect_to @book
    else
      render 'newBook' #if title is not there, just re renders newBook page
    end

  end

  def edit 
    @book = Book.find(params[:id]) #after this, make edit.html.erb
  end

  def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id]) 

    if(@book.update(book_params))
      redirect_to @book
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy 
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book.destroy
    redirect_to books_path
  end

  def mangaList
    @books = Book.all
  end

  private 

  def book_params #can only be accessed from this class #step1 
    params.require(:books).permit(:title, :author, :description)
  end
end
```

I tried adding a :file inside the book_params but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails offers a simple way for uploading files via `ActiveStorage` (there are also few gems which do the same thing but for now you can try `ActiveStorage` as it is build in solution).

Official guides are good resource to start digging into this topic. You can find `ActiveStorage` related article here:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

There are also many tutorials on how to set it up on the Internet. If you are more of video guy GoRails offers nice overview:

https://gorails.com/episodes/file-uploading-with-activestorage-rails-5-2?autoplay=1

Basically you will need to add some configuration to your application and related fields to your models. After this you will be able to pass files in the params to your controller and save their representation in database. This will allow you to retrieve them in the view from instance variables (just as you do now with `title`, `author` and `description`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your help! Problem was solved! Just had to add an image tag, silly me. But I watched the tutorial, very helpful.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

is file an attribute or association?
In which model you're trying to upload file is it book or other association model?

Comment: it's an attribute, just had to add an image tag to my view. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, so for that you can use CarrierWave gem https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave
It's easy to implement please go through the documentation and if you still need help you can ping.